# Windows Phone 8.1 app starts ok via "normal" start but "hangs" via voice command

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, voice-recognition

I have written a simple Windows phone 8.1 app that starts ok when started via the corresponding application icon.
I also have added a voice command definition file and added voice commands.
My Problem now is that when I speak the corresponding voice command the ...

1. voice command is recognized successfully
2. my app is started, i.e. the splash Screen is displayed
3. BUT the splash Screen is displayed for about 15 seconds and then the app is closed.

Where should I continue to investigate? As mentioned above when the app is started via the application Icon it starts successfully.
So what's the difference when an app is started via a voice command and when it is started normally?

Remarks:

- In the code I do NOT react differently, i.e. I do NOT check the way the application is started or try to determine the used voice command ...
- When debugging in the Emulator the voice command successfully starts the app.
  But when the Debugging instance is stopped, the Emulator Shows the same Problem.
- I would post some code but do not know which is the relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have figured out that the problem is fixed by overriding "OnActivated" in App.xaml.cs, which is an alternative entry point to "OnLaunched". OnActivated is used e.g. when the app is started via voice command.